# IE7 Display issues

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

A lot of my floats are showing up on a separate line when viewing in IE7 ... in Ffox, chrome, IE8 etc they look fine.

The site in question is:

http://208.43.52.30

The places where the float is not working are the location for "events near me", "Show" for the show month buttons ..

I'll attach some screenshots

**IE 8:**

[image: IE 8]

**IE 7:**

[image: IE 7]

Comment: I made a really inelegant solution to this .. basically added a bunch of conditional CSS comments for IE7 (and below) .. not perfect no, but necessity ..

Answer (score 1):

I personally can't see the difference (the closest thing I have to IE7 is compatibility view in IE8), but based on your screenshots it looks like the "Upcoming Events" `font-size` is much bigger in the IE7 screenshot.

Did you define `font-size` for your `h1` tag? Different browsers sometimes handle the size and margins of header tags different, so if you put `h1{font-size:14px;}` in your stylesheet maybe it'll fix it.

Comment: @Kevin: well, i mean for you to fill in the appropriate `font-size`; 14px was just an example. try something more like 24px.

Answer (score 1):

The Upcoming Events problem is being causes by IE7 pushing the `float:right` to the next line instead of keeping it in line with the h1, despite no `clear` I can't figure out a way to get that to stop. An alternative I came up with was to float the `h1` left instead and give the default `text-alignment:right;` This will cause the same layout, and IE7 is happy.

http://jsfiddle.net/znRxq/

Same solution for the show button.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work either - it just moved all the text into the middle of the page, even after taking out all the margins/padding..

Comment: Did you look at my example in jsfiddle? From developer tools in console you had the `<div><h1>Title</h1>other stuff</div>` layout. So, try setting the div to text-align:right, and the h1 to float left.

Answer (score 1):

IE7 might be making your input larger (from experience), you should set a different width for IE7.

Answer (score 0):

First off, 'float' is pretty well supported, even on IE. When validating the HTML on you website, I am getting [43 errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://208.43.52.30/event/list) (wont really be that many). Correct those and see if it fixes the problem. Earlier versions of IE (<= 7) are not as friendly to slightly invalid markup as IE8, chrome, firefox, etc...

Second, if you are really just trying to display block elements inline, 'display:inline-block' is the easiest way. Contrary to popular belief, this is supported on IE7 & 8. Here is the css for cross browser support:

```
.inline-element {
  display:-moz-inline-stack;
  display:inline-block;
  zoom:1;
  *display:inline;
}
```

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work... I've now got this:

<pre>
<h2>September 2010 <span class="showButton"><a href="#" class="button blue small">Show</a></span></h2>

With the class:

.showButton {
    float: right;
    display:-moz-inline-stack;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
}
</pre>

Still shows up on a different line